# In Laravel, If I store something with session->put() is that info possibly available to the client browser?

Tags: php, laravel

I hope not, but thought it was worth an ask to make sure I'm understanding how sessions work.

After login, I set various values using $request->session()->put().

I've examined the cookies set in the browser and none of the variables I've set appear to be there...just being extra cautious.

Laravel 11.x.

Comment: the default laravel session driver is `file`. You should see the values you stored somewhere in the `storage/framework` folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel saves session variables on the server side, not in the browser cookies.
**The browser only holds a session ID cookie**, which Laravel uses to access the session data on the server for each request.

Laravel session keeps sensitive information secure by not exposing it directly to the browser.

Comment: To be honest, that's not a feature of Laravel but of PHP.

Comment: @Sitethief Yes, I agree, and we all know that. Whatever we use `$request->session()` (Laravel) under the hood it uses `session_`, `$_SESSION`